# java script failing because of white spaces caracters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, append, haml

I have in my views some code as this

```
$(".someclass").hover(function(){
    $(this).append("#{render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file"}");
});
```

The `show_some_file.html.haml` file consists of two nested basic divs

In my browser, I get

```
$(".someclass").hover(function(){
    $(this).append("<div>
        <div>some text</div>
        </div>
    ");
});
```

On hover, I get in my chrome console `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I deleted my white spaces in my console, and it worked. But how to clean the white spaces in my ruby rendering ?

Comment: I'm not sure about changing something with Ruby, but one option is to use `<script id="some_id" type="text/template">#{render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file"}</script>`. And then to get its content, you could use `$(this).append($("#some_id").html());`. It kind of acts like a template. You use a `script` tag, but you set its `type` to something that doesn't cause it to be executed. Since `script` tags are never visible on a page, you would never have visual problems...unlike doing this inside of a `div`...the HTML is then "separate" from the rest of the page.

Comment: I doubt it's related, but I didn't know you could use quotes inside of quotes as you have.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I'm not sure you *can*, but server side code is evaluated first, so the result isn't nested quotes. It might look weird in the source (unless an IDE picks up on it), but it should end up correct

Comment: @Ian thanks but is it possible to have more straightforward solution ?

Comment: @Newben Unfortunately I don't know. Hopefully someone comes and explains the quick and easy solution that we seem to be missing. I posted an answer just as an alternative, for you or anyone; I'll keep looking for the real solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely certain it will help, but you probably should use the `"<%= render ... %>"` variant rather than the `#{}`

And since it's for javascript, the correct way would be `"<%= escape_javascript(render ...) %>"`

If using HAML, substitute the ERB for however the markup is written there.

Edit: might be
`!= "$(this).append("#{escape_javascript(render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file")}");"`

Comment: you're saying you can use <%= ... %> for HAML file ?

Comment: If you read the last sentence I'm saying nothing of the sort... I'm just assuming you can do everything with HAML you can do with ERB. Looking around, it seems the correct way might be this:

`!= "$(this).append("#{escape_javascript(render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file")}");"`

Comment: ah that's it I found the same response, I didn't see you your edit ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since the result of your `{#render}` is HTML, and although you might use it once, it might make more sense to store it in HTML, and retrieve it with JavaScript. Mimicking templating, here's an example of what I mean:

```
<script id="my_render" type="text/template">
    #{render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file"}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var render_content = $("#my_render").html();
        $(".someclass").hover(function () {
            $(this).append(render_content);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It kind of acts like a template. You use a `script` tag, but you set its `type` to something that doesn't cause it to be executed. Since `script` tags are never visible on a page, you would never have visual problems...unlike doing this inside of a div...the HTML is then "separate" from the rest of the page.

I'm sure there's a better solution using Ruby, but if you're outputting a partial view to JavaScript code, I'd have to ask why. It makes more sense to me to put in a "template". I understand this doesn't directly answer your immediate question, but it's an alternative :)

Comment: thank you Ian, I found some way to do that. Btw I tried to work around with jquery, using trim() or some regex replace and none of them worked

Comment: Awesome, glad you found out how to do it properly! Yeah, trying to "fix" this with JavaScript alone won't work, since the Ruby will be evaluated, sent to the browser, and compiled by the browser...which will throw an exception for the newlines in the string. You'd have to handle it differently (like my answer) or fix it before it got to the browser (like your answer)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I got it, one of the right thing to do is :

```
$("someclass").hover(function(){
            $(this).append("#{escape_javascript render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some title"}");
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

The obvious thing to do is edit layouts/show_some_file & remove white space. It's not really whitespace that's the problem, but carriage returns. Javascript doesn't like multi-line strings. If I knew Ruby, I could probably write a regex that gets rid off stuff like "\r\n", which is carriage return line feed in PHP/C syntax.

Comment: ok, that's a bit like indentation in python. So, rather than insert the file content directly with `#{render "layouts/show_some_file", title: "some_file"}` ruby doesn't allow you to save this to a variable, then remove the returns & insert the string with returns stripped?

Comment: The `escape_javascript` in the upvoted answers is the sort of thing I was suggesting. I just don't know ruby, otherwise I would have come up with it probably. Kind of harsh that I get downvoted just for making a hint instead of solving the problem, not that losing 2 points reputation means squat.